# how to position label inside a pie chart slice

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graphics, label, pie-chart

I'm creating a pie chart and stumbled upon a though:
**how do i place a slice label inside the slice?**

I want the label to be in the middle of the slice and fit inside the slice entirely.

Currently I'm computing the position for the label by `center.y - sliceStartPoint.y / 2` and `sliceStartPoint.x + 10`
but it has poor results.

How to compute label bounds effectively?
The calculation should work for any slice, wide or thin.

Comment: what does your pie chart object look like, we are missing a variable here, namely either the proportion of each value out of the whole (which we can use to calculate the angle and then the mid point) or the actual slice endpoint. I assume you only have the former.

Comment: I have all the variables - startpoint, endpoint, angle, center. I have no problem with drawing chart or finding center of the slice - the problem is that there may be enough space below the center or above it and I dunno how to calculate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in a Pie chart, you most likely would like to place the label in the middle.

where in the circle is no much of a problem:
so if your slice is from `0.1[rad]` to `0.3[rad]` then you should place it along the avarage radious `(0.1[rad] + 0.3[rad])/2 = 0.2[rad]` radius.

the tricky part is where along the radius:
your triangle is 'isosceles' so given height from it's TOP, the width between it's polygonals is easy to determine,
`tg(alpha/2) = (w/2) / h`
`h = w/2 / tg(alpha / 2)`

= edit start =
[image: image presenting the calculation of W]

Build Aid: height through middle
Build Aid: line `AB` parallel to Triangle Base

1. OMB = 90 = 1/4rad (height of the Triangle)
2. AM = BM (isosceles)
3. MOB = Aplha / 2 (isosceles)
4. tg(MOB) = MB/OM
   tg(alpha/2)= (w/2) / h
   h tg(alpha/2) = w/2
   2h tg(alpha/2) = w

tg(a) is a mathematical shorthand for tan(a).
which is a trigonometric function [(easy explanation of Sin, Cos & Tan here)](https://www.mathsisfun.com/sine-cosine-tangent.html)

[JS has Tan() built in (see this link)](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tan.asp)

= edit end =

so determine the width(`w`) you need for your label, and calculate `h`

if `h` is larger than your PIE-Chart radius, you are placing the label outside the Chart, you should consider a constant R for that with a nice looking line.

cheers.

-- Edit 2 --
Note, there are two things to consider :

1. when your slice is larger than `pi`[rad] = 180 deg, the above calculation will fail, but in this situation the label should fit nicely.
2. you should specify at what minimum distance from the center along the radius you want your label, and if `h` comes lesser then, just use the minimum. (i'd say about 0.7r is a good value, but make it configurable.

Comment: Can you explain what tg(alpha) is? How do i apply it in code? And are w and h the width and the height of the label?